# Downgrade from latest nightly build to latest stable version

Tags: errors, upgrade, wordpress-version

I'm currently running `3.6-alpha-23495` and want to go back to the latest stable (currently `3.5.1`).

The site is now up and running.

The reason that I'm going to downgrade is that the following error is appearing:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 311296 bytes) in
/home/USERNAME/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie/Misc.php
on line 843
```

I have added `ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');` to `wp-config.php` to execute the command everywhere, and also added the code at the top of `/wp-includes/SimplePie/Misc.php`, but still no luck.

Anyway I think that the best way to avoid facing with these errors is downgrading to the latest stable version.

Ant ideas? Thank you

Comment: First step: do you have a backup of the database?

Comment: @brasofilo thank you for your comment. Yes, I do have the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps are mostly from this Codex article, [Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update), but in this case a prior database backup is essential.

This is what I do:

1. Upload the [latest WordPress version](http://wordpress.org/download/) to a temporary folder, `/public_html/new-wp`
2. This upload **should not** contain the folder `/wp-content` nor the file `wp-config.php`.
3. If you can, create another database and import the old backup. And in such case, prepare another `wp-config.php` with the new `DB_NAME` information.
4. If another database is not possible, backup its contents just in case, drop all the tables and import the backup.
5. Move all WordPress files (the nightly build) to a temporary folder, e.g., `/public_html/old-wp`. **Don't move** the folder `/wp-content` nor the file `wp-config.php`.
6. Move the new version (`/public_html/new-wp`) to the root.
7. Confirm everything is working and delete the `/old-wp` folder.

Important notes:

- Decide for step 3 or 4 beforehand.
- Backup everything before starting, plugin suggestion: [BackWPup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backwpup/). Or if your cPanel supports it, zip the whole `/public_html` folder or the files you deem necessary.
- I prefer to move files instead of deleting, this is faster when using a FTP client. And when everything is done, I proceed to deletion. Note that WebFTP is *much more faster* for deleting files than a regular application.

Comment: Thank you very much, that should be the way to go. It will prefer the 3rd step over 4th.